# jQuery validator addmethod won't display appropriate error messages

Tags: jquery, error-handling, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate my forms, and I am also using the `addmethod` function to create my own validation methods. This is how I set up jQuery Validator:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#validation_json").length > 0) {
        var validationJSON = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($("#validation_json").val()));
        $(".form-horizontal").validate({
            rules: validationJSON.rules,
            messages: validationJSON.messages
        });
    }
});
```

I have and input tag with the id validation_json, and the value set to a set of rules and messages for the jQuery validator plugin; these rules and messages are output server-side with the help of a form builder. The only issue is that whenever I add my own validation method, like so:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniqueemail", function(email) {
    return false; //just for testing
}, "This email is already in use");
```

jQuery validator will use this method before submitting the field to check if it is valid (in addition the the rules set above), however if one of the `addMethod`'s validates to false, it will use the message for that item set above in the validate method, and not the message passed into `addMethod`. Does anyone know of a way that I could get it to display the message actually passed into the addMethod functions? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UH6Va/) link showing the problem.

Comment: Can you construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle demo above.

Comment: How do I use the demo?  In other words, what should I enter in the email field that is supposed to trigger the custom message?

Comment: if you were to enter any valid email, say test@test.com, then it will still keep saying "Email field is required", even though the test that it's failing is "uniqueemail".

Comment: I see.  How can I know if your `.validate()` rules are formatted and declared properly?  What is the exact result of `validationJSON.rules` and `validationJSON.messages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with how you've set this up...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#validation_json").length > 0) {
        var validationJSON = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($("#validation_json").val()));
        $(".form-horizontal").validate({
            rules: validationJSON.rules,
            messages: validationJSON.messages
        });
    }
});
```

[`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) is used to *initialize* the plugin *once* on DOM ready.  You've put it inside a conditional statement, so the plugin is only *initialized* on the form if the `if` condition is met.  Validation will fail to initialize at all other times.  Use [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to trigger a validation test instead of re-initializing the plugin...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".form-horizontal").validate({
        rules: validationJSON.rules,
        messages: validationJSON.messages,
        // any other options
    });

    if ($("#validation_json").length > 0) {
        var validationJSON = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($("#validation_json").val()));
        $(".form-horizontal").valid();  // trigger a validation test
    }

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniqueemail", function(email) {
        return false; //just for testing
    }, "This email is already in use");

});
```

**Basic Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/AYvmg/

The demo shows that your custom message from `addMethod` is working as expected.

It's possible to then dynamically change the custom message without another call to `.validate()` by using the [`.rules('add')`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) method.

```
$('#yourfield').rules('add', {
    messages: {
        uniqueemail: "this is a new message"
    }
});
```

**Another Basic Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/5RnLM/

This second demo works just like the first.  Then when you click the `#test` button, the message for the rule is changed to something else.  You could use this `.rules('add')` method to change your custom message whenever you need and from any other function.

Otherwise, perhaps you can show the associated HTML and construct a jsFiddle demo to more clearly show the issue you're having.